# change the selectfield width in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, textfield

I have the next code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Select',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    options: [
                        {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
                        {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
                        {text: 'This is a long text to test the selectfield',  value: 'third'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to change the selectfield width since the third option is very long.

Answer (score 1):

There are the [width](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-width) and the [maxWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-cfg-maxWidth) configs for that.

EDIT:

```
div.x-select-overlay { width: 15em !important }
```

Comment: yes, but this changes the selectfield width when it is contracted. when the options are expanded it returns to its original size

Comment: in that case use can probably use CSS:
 div.x-select-overlay { width: 15em !important }

Comment: thanks I have used
.x-select-overlay{
min-width: 25em !important;
} 
and it works

Answer (score 1):

The above result would override the select field overlay in entire application.

To be more precise and accurate, you can override the width or height property by using select field `defaultPhonePickerConfig` or `defaultTabletPickerConfig` in your specific selectfield.eg`.

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    defaultPhonePickerConfig: {
        height: '8em',
        width:'10em'
    },
    defaultTabletPickerConfig: {
        height: '8em',
        width:'10em'
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have finally solved this with:

```
.x-select-overlay{
min-width: 25em !important;
}
```

in app.scss